# Using Ruby Global Variable for Exception $! on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables

I'm trying to access the last exception_message from my rails app by using the ruby global variable $!, but it is coming back at nil despite multiple exceptions having occurred before the variable being called. Does this not work in rails? Is there another way to access the last exception that was raised in the application?

Comment: this seems to work: `0 / 0 rescue $!`

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that $! isn't all that global.  It just works in the call stack of the exception - which I guess makes sense.

https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/working-with-ruby-exceptions-outside-of-the-rescue-block/

"This means that $! is pretty useless inside of a shell like IRB. Often in IRB, I'll run a method and get an exception. Sometimes I'd like to get ahold of that exception object. But $! doesn't work for this."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `$!` always returns `nil`. As I wrote in the comment above, `0 / 0 rescue $!` works but I can't seem to get it to work in any other context.

One way you can access the exception in a Ruby program is by using `=>` after `rescue` like so:

```
[24] pry(main)> begin
[24] pry(main)*   undefined_variable
[24] pry(main)* rescue => e
[24] pry(main)*   puts e
[24] pry(main)* end
undefined local variable or method `undefined_variable' for main:Object
=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks @sixty4bit. I'm able to get it to work inside a rescue but not anywhere else. Like you pointed out, anywhere else it returns nil. Is there any way to retrieve the last exception from outside a rescue?